# SDL2.dll cannot be found by Visual Studio 2017, even though it exists in SDL's lib folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I'm making a template file for an SDL game engine in C++. My build is really basic and I fixed any syntax and function errors, but for some reason Visual Studio won't recognize the SDL2.dll file even though it exists in the lib folder (which I've already added to the project's additional libraries).
The include folder is also linked to the project and it seems like there's no trouble there.

The full error log is:

'2DGameEngine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\omers\source\repos\Project2\x64\Debug\2DGameEngine.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'2DGameEngine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'2DGameEngine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'2DGameEngine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x5b44 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x56b4 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[16436] 2DGameEngine.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.

Will very much appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: The .dll should be in the same directory as the .exe.

Comment: Thanks! I copied it to my project directory and it worked like magic :)

Comment: Please turn your solution into an answer post here - or delete the question. Either way will get it out of the list of unanswered questions.